Python Sudoku Solver: Appling Rules and Breaking Infinite Loops
I am writing sudoku solver python code. But I cannot find problem.
Python cannot finish the code. I do not know what happening but it is like python enters infinite loop. This loop usually affect a row and changing values. Sometimes it write wrong number and continues like this: 
I have create if else statement for this but it is not solving this problem.
Here is my code:
import tkinter
from copy import deepcopy
import time
import threading

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Sudoku Solver")
window.config(padx=30, pady=30)

posibles = []  # adı posibles olacak
entrylist = []
exactvals = []
labellist = []

def create000():
    global posibles
    global exactvals
    for i in range(9):
        posiblesemp = []
        exectemp = []
        for j in range(9):
            posiblesemp.append([])
            exectemp.append(0)
        posibles.append(deepcopy(posiblesemp))
        exactvals.append(deepcopy(exectemp))
        posiblesemp.clear()
        exectemp.clear()
    return posibles


# def solve():
#     def check(i,j):
#         global posibles
#         for i in range(9):
#             for j in range(9):
#                 for element in posibles[i][j]:
#                     if j == 9:


def solve():
    # def set_text(x, y, text):
    #     u = threading.Thread(target=set_text_wouthreading, args=(x, y, text))
    #     u.start()
    #     u.join()

    def set_text(x, y, text):  # set_text_wouthreading idi.
        global labellist
        if len(posibles[x][y]) == 1:
            return
        elif str(text) == "":
            labellist[x][y].config(text=str(text), background="gray")
        elif text != 0:
            labellist[x][y].config(text=str(text), background="red")
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        return

    def is_in_3x3(element, columnpart, rowpart):
        for m in range(3):
            for n in range(3):
                if element == exactvals[3*columnpart + m][3*rowpart + n]: return False


    def check(i, j):

        def nexcheck(i,j):   #to engele borders
            pass

        print("check")
        global posibles
        global exactvals

        if len(posibles[i][j]) == 1:
            if j != 8:
                if check(i, j+1) == "ok": return True
            elif i != 8:
                if check(i+1, 0) == "ok": return True


        columnpart = int(i / 3)
        rowpart = int(j / 3)
        for element in range(1, 10):
        # for element in posibles[i][j]:

            found = False
            print(element)
            set_text(i, j, element)

            # 3x3 func oluşturcaz
            if is_in_3x3(element, columnpart, rowpart) == False:
                set_text(i, j, "")
                continue

            elif (element in exactvals[i]) or (element in [row[j] for row in exactvals]):
                set_text(i, j, "")
                continue

            elif j != 8:
                exactvals[i][j] = element
                if check(i, j + 1) != "ok":
                    exactvals[i][j] = 0
                    set_text(i, j, "")
                    continue

            elif i != 8:
                exactvals[i][j] = element
                if check(i + 1, 0) != "ok":
                    exactvals[i][j] = 0
                    set_text(i, j, "")
                    continue

            else:
                set_text(i, j, element)
                return "ok"


    check(0, 0)
    return exactvals


def collect_data():  # collec ederken zaten var  i j kullanıp uctan ekleyebiliriz
    global posibles
    global exactvals
    global labellist
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):  # yatay liste değiştiriyor
            if len(entrylist[i][j].get()) != 0:
                value = [int(entrylist[i][j].get())]
                exc = int(entrylist[i][j].get())
                labellist[i][j].config(text=exc, background="lightgreen")
            else:
                value = [x + 1 for x in range(9)]
                exc = 0
            posibles[i][j] = value
            exactvals[i][j] = exc
    window.update()
    solve()
    return posibles

for row in range(9):
    tempentry = []
    for column in range(9):
        a = tkinter.Entry(width=3)
        a.grid(column=column, row=row)
        tempentry.append(a)
    entrylist.append(tempentry)

emptylabel = tkinter.Label(width=3)
emptylabel.grid(column=9,row=0,rowspan=9)

for row in range(9):
    templabel = []
    for column in range(10, 19):
        a = tkinter.Label(width=3,borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        a.grid(column=column, row=row)
        templabel.append(a)
    labellist.append(templabel)


but_solve = tkinter.Button(command=collect_data, text="SOLVE", width=9, pady=5)
but_solve.grid(columnspan=3, row=9, column=3)

create000()

window.mainloop()

I want to solve problem related sudoku rules and break the endless loop.

This is how you could approach it: remove all code that has to do with tkinter (game logic and IO concerns should be separated, and your problem is about game logic). Remove all comments that have code in them. Then debug.

You should also consider not using global variables at all. It's a bad idea to use them. If a function needs to access a variable pass it as a parameter.
